# Got stuck in dynamically allocating an associative array in bash

Tags: bash

I try to create an associative array in bash like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

declare -a arr
while read key
do
    arr+=([$key]=1)
done < /dev/stdin

for i in ${!arr[@]}
do
    echo "key:$i,value:${arr[$i]}"
done
```

I have inputed "leopard" and "longtuan" as a key,the output supposed to be like this in my mind:

```
key:leopard,value:1
key:longtuan,value:1
```

But I only got:

```
key:0,value:11
```

How can I get through of this problem, Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a regular array not an associative array. Change this:

```
declare -a arr
```

into this:

```
declare -A arr
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found that my bash version don't support -A option.

Answer (score 2):

Associative arrays are declared with capital A:

```
declare -A arr
```

`declare -a` declares a regular array.